# Does table order matter in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Or will the optimizer figure it out for you?

For example, is

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (id)
```

The same as

```
SELECT * FROM t2 JOIN t1 USING (id)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For inner joins, the order does not matter.

For outer joins the order does matter.

If you want to force a certain order, you can use a [`STRAIGHT_JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).

Answer (score 1):

**`explain`**

In the case you present, the query planner should always be able to figure it out. But, sometimes things are not always that simple.

If you really want to know how the query will execute then type `explain` before the query:

```
explain SELECT * FROM t2 JOIN t1 USING (id);
```

If you get the same answer for both queries then the optimizer has figured out the 'best' way to join the tables.