# Is more efficient to join T2 to T1 rather than T1 to T2 when T1 has many T2 with a condition held in T2? Or it's the same?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I know the followings queries return the same:

```
SELECT `cimgs`.* 
FROM `cimgs`
INNER JOIN `cimgs_tags` ON `cimgs_tags`.`cimg_id` = `cimgs`.`id`
WHERE `cimgs_tags`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (cimgs.id != 1)

SELECT `cimgs`.*
FROM `cimgs_tags`
INNER JOIN `cimgs` ON `cimgs`.`id` = `cimgs_tags`.`cimg_id`
WHERE `cimgs_tags`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (cimgs.id != 1)
```

But, at a first glance I would say that the first one duplicates the `cimgs` table for each tag before checking the conditions, when the second one check the conditions and then it joins the corresponding tables...

Though I don't know if MySQL detects and optimize this automatically and these two queries have a similar performance?

Comment: that's the job of the optimizer...

Comment: Well you should do a benchmark to test, but from what I've read one of the first optimizations applied is reordering the joins to be the most efficient.  In the case of just two tables, I can't imagine it would make a difference, even without an optimizer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query optimizer will do this for you. It will use the index statistics, which you should keep up to date with [ANALYSE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html). You can force te join order using [STRAIGHT_JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) though, and you can force to use certain indexes, too.

You can do an explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `cimgs`.* 
FROM `cimgs`
INNER JOIN `cimgs_tags` ON `cimgs_tags`.`cimg_id` = `cimgs`.`id`
WHERE `cimgs_tags`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (cimgs.id != 1)

EXPLAIN SELECT `cimgs`.*
FROM `cimgs_tags`
INNER JOIN `cimgs` ON `cimgs`.`id` = `cimgs_tags`.`cimg_id`
WHERE `cimgs_tags`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (cimgs.id != 1)
```

to see the differences.

Offcourse, for a LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN, there is a semantic difference.

Comment: Thanks! I was very worried about this can cause problem in a future with many records.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter from INNER JOINS. In the same fashion neither does WHERE clause order

```
WHERE `cimgs_tags`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (cimgs.id != 1)

WHERE (cimgs.id != 1) AND `cimgs_tags`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

- The optimiser knows this
- SQL is declarative not procedural. That is, you say "what" and the optimiser decides "how"

Comment: you say "what" and the optimiser decides "how". That is how it is supposed to work. In real life, the optimiser sometimes makes horrible mistakes and you have to kick it around a bit.

Comment: @Thilo: As queries get more complex, yes. Usually it's because optimisers are cost based: it may take 2 weeks to find the perfect plan so it does "good enough". Which may not be of course. 2nd guessing optimisers only works for the data, indexes, distribution etc at the time and may not last though

Comment: "only works for the data, indexes, distribution etc at the time and may not last though". Yes. It is a tricky problem. I don't expect the optimizer to get it right for complex queries or skewed data. My problem is that once you get to the point where the declarative approach fails, you are having a hard time coercing the system to "behave" with hints or the like. Would be nice to have a "programmatic" alternative to SQL sometime, where you spell out the execution plan you want explicitly. None of this would be a real problem if a bad execution plan was just 2 times slower, but it can be x1000.

Comment: @Thilo: I've found that things like derived tables help the optimiser because a WHERE would be applied earlier, or change LEFT JOIN to EXISTS to force a semi-join, or use a temp table to break it down, Summary: can still be declarative without hints or forcing, just refined

Comment: Sure, there are all kinds of tricks to "help the optimiser". But this is getting into "black magic area". If it is declarative, declaring the same thing slightly differently should make no difference (which after all was the gist of this question).

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250805/does-table-order-matter-in-mysql)

answers your question.

"For inner joins, the order does not matter.
For outer joins the order does matter.
If you want to force a certain order, you can use a STRAIGHT_JOIN."